# How to let extension packages customize UI of base package

Tags: lightning-web-components, aura, isv, custom-metadata, managed-extension

Salesforce is bringing out a lot of new things to make Lightning UI more flexible: [Dynamic Forms](https://admin.salesforce.com/blog/2019/break-up-your-record-details-with-dynamic-forms), [Dynamic Interactions](https://admin.salesforce.com/blog/2021/introducing-dynamic-interactions-the-latest-low-code-innovation-for-salesforce-platform), etc. But they are not ISV-friendly because they are based on `Flexipages`. And Flexipages [are not completely upgradable and are ownable by ISV](https://albasfdc.com/2018/09/09/lightning-pages-and-managed-packages/)s.

**What are Salesforce and other AppExchange ISVs recommending for building UI extensible by partners?**

*Pages or Components for Partner A record types should display Partner A embedded components and Partner B type pages should display Partner B UI.*

[image]

I only see very unflexible options:

1. Base Package contains Generic `Aura` Component that renders Partner component based on information in `CMDT` records packaged by Partner. Salesforce doesn't allow this in `LWC`.
2. `IFrames`, `Canvas` Apps

Comment: You can use components from other namespaces directly in a flexipage and Salesforce are heading towards cross-namespace use of components for component composition. I suspect this latter will allow you to do what you want to do by providing packaged components with slots etc. but it was only [recently announced](https://appexchangetechtalkapril222021.splashthat.com/) as something they are going to make available.

Comment: Episode 24? I can't recall this. Can you share more. In an answer. Heresay is also ok :-)

Answer (score 4):

In a [recent AppExchange Tech Talk](https://appexchangetechtalkapril222021.splashthat.com/), Salesforce revealed that they will allow cross-namespace use of exposed LWCs. This would, for example, allow a package developer to create a component, let's call it "example", in their package with a namespace prefix we'll call "funky" and have it available for use by third parties (my highlighting in a screenshot from the tech talk):

[image: Cross-namespace LWCs]

With an exposed component this can currently be used in flexipages both within and outside the package.

Additionally, right now and within the package, you can use that component for "component composition". For example, you might have another component that uses the "example" component in its template, thus:

```
<template>
  <c-example>
    <slots>...</slots>
  </c-example>

  <c-something-else></c-something-else>
<template>
```

With the up-coming change, the "example" component could **also** be used in a subscriber org or extension package LWC's template, like:

```
<template>
  <funky-example>
    <slots>...</slots>
  </funky-example>
</template>
```

Comment: That is nice but still would require a subscriber admin to compile his flexipages on his own. What I need (and I enhanced my question) is a way for a Base package UI to dynamically embed arbitrary Partner components that follow a certain contract but are unknow during package time.

Comment: So really you are discussing dynamic component creation, based on some meta description, right? What's the basic difference between using CMT instances you require the admin to create, and having the admin construct a page (visually) in the App Builder? Do you want to re-use the same CMTs in multiple contexts, is that it?

Comment: The CMDT is part of the Base Package and the Partners are packaging records of it in their extension package. During runtime (UI render) the base Package code is reading those CMDT records and rendering the UI dynamically (without any subscriber admin having to do it)

Comment: So the equivalent would be to have the extension package include further flexipages from which the subscriber can choose...? What I am saying is you have a choice here (until dynamic LWC creation is available) of using Aura (for dynamic creation) and your CMTs OR using flexipages...